# How to increase ReplicationFactor?

Tags: apache-kafka

I increased the number of partitions of a Kafka topic using `Kafka Manager`.

Now it looks like

```
Topic:query.topic   PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
Topic: query.topic  Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1 Isr: 1
Topic: query.topic  Partition: 1    Leader: none    Replicas: 2 Isr:
Topic: query.topic  Partition: 2    Leader: none    Replicas: 0 Isr:
```

Did I break something? Why there is no leader for the last two partitions and no In-sync replicas?

I tried making PartitionCount to 1 again, but it wouldn't let me do that.

Also, what I actually wanted to do was to increase `ReplicationFactor`, so that it is fault-tolerant in failure of a node. How can I do this?

Shown below is a description of another topic that was correctly configured.

```
Topic:metric.topic  PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:2 Configs:
Topic: metric.topic Partition: 0    Leader: 2   Replicas: 2,1   Isr: 2
Topic: metric.topic Partition: 1    Leader: 0   Replicas: 0,2   Isr: 0
Topic: metric.topic Partition: 2    Leader: 0   Replicas: 1,0   Isr: 0
```